# puppeteer with aws lambda function ro scrape data .Failed to launch chrome

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, google-chrome, aws-lambda, puppeteer

I face some issue while using puppeteer with **aws lambda** Failed to launch chrome! node version 12.x

````
{ errorType: 'Error',
  errorMessage:
   'Failed to launch chrome! spawn ./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT\n\n\nTROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md\n',
  trace:
   [ 'Error: Failed to launch chrome! spawn ./node_modules/puppeteer/.local-chromium/linux-722234/chrome-linux/chrome ENOENT',
     '',
     '',
     'TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/GoogleChrome/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/troubleshooting.md',
     '',
     '    at onClose (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:342:14)',
     '    at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/puppeteer-core/lib/Launcher.js:333:64)',
     '    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:223:5)',
     '    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:270:12)',
     '    at onErrorNT (internal/child_process.js:456:16)',
     '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:81:21)' ] }```
````

Comment: Make sure you are running with headless mode.

Answer (score 0):

you should use chrome-aws-lambda (https://github.com/alixaxel/chrome-aws-lambda)

just change the import to

```
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
```

and call puppeteer call to

```
browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
  args: chromium.args,
  defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
  executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
  headless: chromium.headless,
  ignoreHTTPSErrors: true,
});
```